# How can I work with poplib when my email has many multiple folders?

Tags: python, email, poplib

Multiple folders like inbox, dustbin, outbox and so on. The python module `poplib` seen just searches the inbox.

How can I search all of my email? And can I choose just one of them?

[image]

I want to get the number `11818` and the number `611`.

Comment: `imaplib` might be more suitable: https://www.codemiles.com/python-tutorials/reading-email-in-python-t10271.html

Comment: poplib can't do that?

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything online that digs into multiple directories using it. Have you tried using python's repl to dig into the package?

Comment: I change to imaplib. But meet a new problem, the .list() can't list all mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer. It's my mail server problem. It saved all mails 30days ago into to a folder that storage in cloud. So .list() can't find it.
Now, I change the set, the .list() work.